# ComboBox Items from a for loop method

Tags: c#

I. MY METHOD

```
 private void itemLoop(int start, int finish)
            {
                finish += 1;
                System.Object[] itemobj = new System.Object[finish];
                for (int i = start; i <= finish; i++)
                {
                    itemobj[i] = i;
                }
            }
```

II. I can't call the method. How can I call this method to create a range of items in ComboBox using loop?

```
this.cbMonth.Items.AddRange(itemLoop(1, 12));
```

Comment: The return type of that method is `void`. Why do you think you could pass `void` to `AddRange`?

Comment: The method `itemLoop` does not return the items. So nothing is added.

Answer (score 4):

there is no need to implement a custom range method

```
this.cbMonth.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1,12));
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is the one that Fubo has explained.

```
this.cbMonth.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1,12));
```

But if you have to use your method, you have to return the array:

```
            private System.Object[] ItemLoop(int start, int finish)
            {
                finish += 1;
                System.Object[] itemobj = new System.Object[finish];
                for (int i = start; i <= finish; i++)
                {
                    itemobj[i] = i;
                }
                return itemobj;
            }
```

At the end you can call this:

```
this.cbMonth.Items.AddRange(ItemLoop(1, 12));
```